# How to use picker to assign roles to users on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, picker, user-roles

How do I create a picker that gives the user the ability to select his user role (i.e. student, faculty, or security) when creating his account. I've created a flag for each role, student = 1, faculty = 2, and security =3. I want to store the flag value with all the other information that the user has entered onto Firebase Realtime Database. I've created the picker but don't know how set it up so that "when this roles is selected then add this flag to the user".

Here is my code:

FirebaseHelper.cs

```
    //Insert a user
    public static async Task<bool> AddUser(string email, string password, string studentid,
                                            string firstname, string lastname, string carmake,
                                            string carmodel, string caryear, string carcolor,
                                            string licensenumber)
    {
        try
        {


            await firebase
            .Child("Users")
            .PostAsync(new Users()
            {
                Email = email,
                Password = password,
                StudentID = studentid,
                FirstName = firstname,
                LastName = lastname,
                CarMake = carmake,
                CarModel = carmodel,
                CarYear = caryear,
                CarColor = carcolor,
                LicenseNumber = licensenumber,
                SetAccountType = AccountType.student,
                SetAccountStatus = AccountStatus.unlcoked,
                NumberOfCitations = 0
            });
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Error:{e}");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

SignUpPage.xaml (where i have the picker)

```
                        <Label Text="Select your Role" FontSize="Default" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="Black" />
                        <Picker x:Name="picker"
                             Title="Select a role"
                             TitleColor="Black">
                          <Picker.ItemsSource>
                            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                                 <x:String>Student</x:String>
                                 <x:String>Faculty</x:String>
                                 <x:String>Security</x:String>
                             </x:Array>
                          </Picker.ItemsSource>
                         </Picker>
                        <Button x:Name="signup" Text="Sign Up" BackgroundColor="#0077be" TextColor="White" Command="{Binding SignUpCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding SignEnable}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

SignUpPage.xaml.cs

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class SignUpPage : ContentPage
{
    SignUpVM signUpVM;
    public SignUpPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        signUpVM = new SignUpVM();
        //set binding
        BindingContext = signUpVM;
    }
}
```

SignUpVM.cs

```
public class SignUpVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private bool signenable = true;

    public bool SignEnable
    {
        get { return signenable; }
        set 
        {
            signenable = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SignEnable"));
        }
    }

    private bool truefalse = false;
    public bool Truefalse
    {
        get { return truefalse; }
        set
        {
            truefalse = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Truefalse"));
        }
    }

    private string email;
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set
        {
            email = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Email"));
        }
    }

    private string studentid;
    public string StudentID
    {
        get { return studentid; }
        set
        {
            studentid = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StudentID"));
        }
    }

    private string firstname;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstname; }
        set
        {
            firstname = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"));
        }
    }

    private string lastname;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastname; }
        set
        {
            lastname = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastName"));
        }
    }


    private string password;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set
        {
            password = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Password"));
        }
    }

    private string confirmpassword;
    public string ConfirmPassword
    {
        get { return confirmpassword; }
        set
        {
            confirmpassword = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ConfirmPassword"));
        }
    }
    public Command SignUpCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                // Read email address from Firebase database
                var user = await FirebaseHelper.GetUser(Email);
                // Check for symbols
                var hasSymbols = new Regex(@"[!@#$%^&*()_+=\[{\]};:<>|./?,-]");
                Truefalse = true;
                SignEnable = false;
                //null or empty field validation, check weather email and password is null or empty
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
                {
                    Truefalse = false;
                    SignEnable = true;
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Empty Values", "Please enter Email and Password", "OK");
                }
                else if (!Email.Contains("@"))
                {
                    Truefalse = false;
                    SignEnable = true;
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Email Address is Invalid", "OK");
                }
                else if (Password.Length < 8)
                {
                    Truefalse = false;
                    SignEnable = true;
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Password is less than 8 characters", "OK");
                }
                else if (!Password.Any(char.IsUpper))
                {
                    Truefalse = false;
                    SignEnable = true;
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Password Must Contain at Least 1 Uppcase Letter", "OK");
                }
                else if (!hasSymbols.IsMatch(Password))
                {
                    Truefalse = false;
                    SignEnable = true;
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Password should contain At least one special case characters", "OK");
                }
                else if (Password != ConfirmPassword)
                {
                    Truefalse = false;
                    SignEnable = true;
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Password must be same as above!", "OK");
                }
                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StudentID))
                {
                    Truefalse = false;
                    SignEnable = true;
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Empty Values", "Please enter Student ID", "OK");
                }
                else if (StudentID.Length < 9)
                {
                    Truefalse = false;
                    SignEnable = true;
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Student ID is Incorrect!", "OK");
                }
                else if (user != null)
                {
                    if (Email == user.Email)
                    {
                        Truefalse = false;
                        SignEnable = true;
                        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Email Taken", "Please Use A Different Email", "Ok");
                    }
                }
                else
                    SignUp();

            });

        }

    }
    private async void SignUp()
    {
        //call AddUser function which we define in Firebase helper class
        var user = await FirebaseHelper.AddUser(Email, Password, StudentID, FirstName, LastName, CarMake, CarModel,
                                                CarYear, CarColor, LicenseNumber);
        //AddUser return true if data insert successfuly 
        if (user)
        {

            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("SignUp Success", "", "Ok");
            //Navigate to Wellcom page after successfuly SignUp
            //pass user email to welcom page
            SignEnable = true;
            Truefalse = false;
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
        }
        else
        {
            SignEnable = true;
            Truefalse = false;
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "SignUp Fail", "OK");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

just check the value of `Picker` and set the `AccountType` appropriately

in the code behind, get the value of the picker

```
// default to student
var acctType = AccountType.Student;

if (picker.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Faculty") acctType = AccountType.Faculty; 
if (picker.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Security") acctType = AccountType.Security;
```

then pass this through your VM down to your DB layer

```
await firebase
        .Child("Users")
        .PostAsync(new Users()
        {
            ...
            SetAccountType = acctType,
            ...
        });
```

Comment: Would this be added on the SignUpPage.xaml.cs

Comment: you posted way too much code for me to explain each individual edit to you.  But you would probably get the Picker value in the code behind of your page, and then pass that down to your VM and then your DB code

Comment: sorry about that, I'm new to Xamarin and posting questions. I'll give your advise a try. Thanks

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT haven't had a chance to apply it

Comment: Ok, you can try it when you feel free.